# Excepciones en plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

veréis, tengo este código en plpgsql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION edatAlumne(int id_alumn) RETURNS int AS $$

    DECLARE

        edat integer;

    BEGIN

        select extract(year from age(current_date, naixement)) 
        into edat
        from alumnes
        where id_alumn = id

        return edat;
    EXCEPTION

        IF id_alumn = null THEN
            return null;


    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

El enunciado dice que debo crear una función que debe retornar la edad del alumno, identificando al mismo a través de la ID (esa parte está hecha), pero el problema viene cuando mencionan el tema de excepciones puesto que:

> El enunciado dice que la función debe retornar null si el parámetro es null o no existe el alumno, y es ahí donde voy perdido, puesto que no manejo muy bien el tema excepciones, ya que acabo de empezar, alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver si entendí bien la pregunta.

> El enunciado dice que la función debe retornar null si el parámetro es null

para solucionar ese punto simplemente hay que preguntar si el parámetro es null o no.

ejemplo.

```
if id_alumn is null then
    return null;
```

> o no existe el alumno

para verificar si no existe un alumno debemos manejar la exception NO_DATA_FOUND que se dispara cuando la consulta no retorna datos.

ejemplo.

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Alumno inexistente!';
```

**RAISE EXCEPTION** genera un error que el usuario visualizará con el texto que indiques.

El ejemplo completo es el siguiente.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION edatAlumne(int id_alumn) RETURNS int AS $$

DECLARE

    edat integer;

BEGIN

    if id_alumn is null then
        return null;
    else
        select extract(year from age(current_date, naixement)) 
        into edat
        from alumnes
        where id = id_alumn;

        return edat;
    end if;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Alumno inexistente!';

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda. Saludos!